# bash script syntax error in expression

Tags: bash, syntax, expression

In a bash script I have to find the running time of a proccess, I do it with this command:

```
PROCCESS_TIME=$(ps -eo pid,etimes | grep $(ps -ef | grep SCREEN | grep PROCCESS | head -1 | awk '{print $2}') | awk '{print $2}')
```

Which gives me running time in seconds,then I need to convert it to minutes

```
PROCCESS_TIME_MIN=$(( $PROCCESS_TIME / 60 ))
```

It works most of the time but sometimes give me this error and script exits

```
0 / 60 : syntax error in expression (error token is "0 / 60 ")
```

or:

```
1893 / 60 : syntax error in expression (error token is "1893 / 60 ")
```

Where is my problem, How to solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will get that error message in this situation:

```
PROCCESS_TIME="0
0"
PROCCESS_TIME_MIN=$(( $PROCCESS_TIME / 60 ))
```

Check

```
PROCCESS_TIME=$(ps -eo pid,etimes | grep something | awk '{print $2}')
```

This can return more than 1 result. You can add `|head -1` in the command, or change the `awk`: `awk '{print $2; exit}'`.
When you change your variables to lowercase,  correct the spelling of proccess_time and use braces, the command will look like

```
process_time=$(ps -eo pid,etimes | 
   grep $(ps -ef | grep SCREEN | grep PROCCESS | awk '{print $2;exit}') |
   awk '{print $2; exit}')
```

I would try to change this command so that you would need 1 `ps` and 1 `awk`, but I have a different `ps` command (without `-o etimes` but with `-o etime`, returning time as `hh:mm:ss`).
Also try to use `grep -E "SCREEN.*PROCCESS"` or `grep -E "PROCCESS.*SCREEN"`

Comment: I thought PROCCESS_TIME could  return multiple values, and I already have the " | head -1" in it if you check.
will try with exit and see how it goes.
I need etimes because in next commands I have:
if [[ $PROCESS_TIME -ge $MINIMUM_TIME ]] ;then ....

Comment: You had 2 `grep` commands, and only one of those (that is used as a `grep`-argument) with a `head -1`.

Comment: Missed the 2nd grep, added next `| head -1` and it looks like its solved. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using a variable for 60(I am simply giving it name as sixty, you could change it as per your need too) and try following then:

```
sixty=60
var=$((PROCCESS_TIME / sixty))
```

Comment: Then you have to either show us the complete code or use `set -x` in starting of your script to get the traces and let us know on same.